# On a product page how could i hide HTML Add to cart button from condition in Controller in Opencart

Tags: model-view-controller, opencart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhuyY.jpg)i am editing a website, the owner wants to hide the Add To Cart button from Product page if the Stock Quantity is less than 1.
it is Opencart 3.0, by MVC concept. An the Problem is that in controller with an IF condition i am writting javascript. When i write simple alert box, it works, but when i am calling button from its ID, it doesn't do anything...

'''    document.getElementById("#button-cart").style.display=:"none !important";     config->get('config_stock_display')) {    $data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];    }    else {    $data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');    }'''

Comment: do you want to hide add to cart button if the product is less than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide **Add to Cart** button in product page if the product is less than 1

Go to catalog/controller/product/product.php

Find this

```
$data['model'] = $product_info['model'];
```

Add This after

```
$data['quantity'] = $product_info['quantity'];
```

Now go to catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.twig

find for

```
<button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="{{ text_loading }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">{{ button_cart }}</button>
```

now replace it with this

```
{% if quantity >= 1 %}
   <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="{{ text_loading }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">{{ button_cart }}</button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You could use `{% if quantity > 0 %}`

Comment: Okay Sir. I tried your code and finished with success... Thanks

Comment: can you help me with another question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551510/i-want-to-change-payment-methods-default-functionality-as-payment-method-use-t

Comment: @MuhammadAmeemKhan Could you accept the answer if it helps you?